# Codeigniter Oracle and CI_SESSIONS

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session, oracle10g

So I have had to make a few modifications to get Oracle to work with CI_SESSIONS. First I had to update the table in the config to be all uppercase. Second I extended the Session library class and overrode the create_session method so that it used all uppercase row names.

However, on insert im still getting an error. The weird thing about it is that when I run the sql in the error in pl/sql developer it works fine. row inserts without a problem.

Here is the sql:

```
INSERT INTO "CI_SESSIONS" ("SESSION_ID", "IP_ADDRESS", "USER_AGENT", "LAST_ACTIVITY", "USER_DATA") VALUES ('9df2c8be0e378bbfdc82a2808c1b3994', '172.16.1.86', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36', 1395328370, '')
```

Im at a loss for what to do next because its WORKING on my side but still erroring on the front end.

Full error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

INSERT INTO "CI_SESSIONS" ("SESSION_ID", "IP_ADDRESS", "USER_AGENT", "LAST_ACTIVITY", "USER_DATA") VALUES ('9df2c8be0e378bbfdc82a2808c1b3994', '172.16.1.86', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36', 1395328370, '')

Filename: /home/bgarrison/public_html/libraries/MY_Session.php

Line Number: 34
```

I am currently using Oracle 10g enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the scheme of `ci_sessions` table so that `user_data` does not have the `NOT NULL` constraint.

The fault is the way Oracle treats `NULL` and `''` the same in some circumstances.

The example schema for the `ci_sessions` table from http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

imposes the `NOT NULL` constraint on `user_data`.

In the INSERT SQL statement the last value (for `user_data`) is `''` which in this case Oracle treats the same as `NULL` which breaks the `NOT NULL` constraint. To get around this you need to change the scheme of `ci_sessions` table so that `user_data` does not have this constraint.